# Using Java 7 CommonDataSource with Scala

Tags: scala, jdbc, datasource, java-7

There seems to be a problem compiling Scala code that uses older (Java 6) JDBC DataSource drivers with the Java 7 JVM and Scala.

In Java 7, Oracle added a new method, `Logger getParentLogger()`, to the `CommonDataSource` interface. Older classes built with Java 6 that implement `CommonDataSource` are not going to implement this method (e.g. `PGConnectionPoolDataSource` and `SQLServerDataSource`). When the code is compiled with the Scala compiler, it complains that the concrete class does not implement the abstract method `getParentLogger`.

I do not know if this happens with the Java compiler, but I suspect not, as it should have been caught by unit testing.

I am sure that this problem will occur with any interface that adds new method declarations.

Is there any work-around for Scala for this problem? Is the only solution to revert to JDK 6? I do not have source code for the SQL Server driver, so I can't fix the problem myself (I know that open-source doesn't have this issue, but I am forced to use that driver for other reasons).

Comment: What code is complaining? Are you trying to instantiate a `SQLServerDataSource`, extend it, or are you doing something else?

Comment: `new SQLServerDataSource { ... }` Trying to extend it as an anonymous subclass (setting things like host, etc. inside the braces). I also tried creating an instance, then initializing the properties **and it worked**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the missing method in your anonymous subclass.

```
new SQLServerDataSource {
  def getParentLogger: Logger = null
  // other stuff
}
```

This little oddity is actually a nice feature of the JVM, allowing some level of backward compatibility when you add methods to interfaces. <strike>I believe you'll have the same behavior with Java as you're seeing with Scala.</strike> Looks like Java *is* a bit more tolerant of missing method definitions in these cases. I'm not exactly sure why, but my guess is that it may have to do with how traits are implemented.

Adding a method to an interface is a kind of change that's [binary compatibly but source incompatible](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~darcy/OpenJdkDevGuide/OpenJdkDevelopersGuide.v0.777.html#compatibility). This is why you can create instances of `SQLServerDataSource` directly. If you tried to invoke `getParentLogger` on that instance, the compiler will allow you to do it, but you'll get a `AbstractMethodError` at runtime.

In order to instantiate your anonymous inner class, it must implement all abstract methods in order to be a concrete class. Since `SQLServerDataSource` doesn't provide an implementation of `getParentLogger`, you have to in your subclass.

Comment: Why does the same thing work in Java without the concrete method definition? Is Java more tolerant of missing abstract methods in pre-compiled classes?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more details. It's basically the difference between binary compatibility and source compatibility.